# How to annotate a queryset with time extracted from timestamp in seconds?

Tags: django, django-models, python-datetime

I have a model with `record_time` field which is of `IntegerField` type. It stores timestamp in seconds (Unix epoch time). I need to annotate the queryset with time only which should be extracted from `record_time`. I came up with this so far

```
annotated_qs = WorkerData.objects.annotate(
    time_e=datetime.fromtimestamp(F('record_time')).time()
)
```

But this results in error (which make sense):

> an integer is required (got type F)

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're looking for correctly, it sounds like you're looking for something like this (for an integer timestamp):  int(time.time())

Comment: @EdKohler More specifically: `for integer in timestamp: time = datetime.fromtimestamp(integer).time()
)`. `time` will be of `datetime.time` type.